# Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp. when i connect with my home router Network

Tags: node.js, mongodb, networking, mongoose

`Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.`

i get this error when i connect with my home router Network - using a Dlink Router DIR-825.
But if i connect to any other Network for eg. Mobile Hotspot - it gets connected

what could be the possible solution ?

Comment: That looks like an incomplete hostname.  How are you trying to connect?

Comment: @Joe i just removed the hostname  as its confidentional ... but yes.. if i terminate the process and connect other network and run... its connecting db

Comment: @AyushAgarwal you solve this issue?

Comment: @gaskbr no sir, still connecting with a different neworking and working

Answer (score 3):

It was ISP DNS Issue
i changed my DNS to Google DNS in my router settings and worked !!!

Comment: It worked for me too! Here is a link on [how to change your DNS to Google DNS](https://www.techworm.net/2016/08/change-default-dns-google-dns-fast-internet-speeds.html) in case someone stumbles upon this error in the future.